# Splunk Extract a Json Format Field In an Event

Tags: json, events, splunk

I have an event, and it was not json format but has an json format field `git_info`, like this

```
2019-11-22 09:05:34.000, iterationName="201903", projectName="project1", pkg_id="16505", pkg_name="NGTS_V1.1.9_SIM_20191122.zip", pkg_size="84.0 MB", create_time="2019-11-22 09:05:34", git_info="[
  {
    "branch": "develop",
    "repoURL": "url1",
    "commitId": "2c977fa"
  }
]", upload_type="auto", in_dev="1", in_snapshot="0", in_release="0"
```

I want extract git_info field and stats the number of branch and repo and other statistics. 
How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

```
index=foo | spath input=git_info
```